# Need to refresh the page manually

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm using kind of an old PHP version which is 5.4.I have covered some HTML contents in PHP if condition not to show only for employee user type. The problem is when I login as an admin I will see the admin content. Then after logout, I log in as an employee I still can see the admin content in the page which should not be the case.

That page is like this:

Header.php + content.php + footer.php

**Header.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

//print_r($_SESSION); for debugging purpose
if(!isset($_SESSION['uname'])){

 header("Location:index.php");
}
$baseurl = "http://localhost/yauwana-fyp-hrm/trunk/";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Rising Logistics</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and  media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js">   </script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"> </script>
<![endif]-->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- suggession text box -->
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      href="css/jquery-ui.css" />

</head>

<body>
<header>
<div class="container padded-top">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#" title="Rising Logistics">
                    <img src="<?php echo $baseurl; ?>images/logo.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="dropdown pull-right admin-area">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="login-menu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    Welcome <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['uname']; ?></strong>
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="login-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="includes/logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-ms-12">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default top-navbar" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
               </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="./" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Recruitement</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
                      <li><a href="template1.php?tab=home">Vacancies</a></li>
                      <li><a href="template1.php?tab=vacancies">Listed Candidates</a></li>
                      <li><a href="template1.php?tab=add_vac">Add Candiate</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  <li><a href="./" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Performance</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
                      <li><a href="template1.php?tab=kpi_list">KPI List</a></li>
                      <li><a href="template1.php?tab=add_kpi">Add KPI</a></li>
                      <li><a href="template1.php?tab=add_reviews">Add Reviews</a></li>
                      <li><a href="template1.php?tab=reviews">Reviews</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  <li><a href="./" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Leave</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
                      <li><a href="template1.php?tab=add_leave">Add Leave</a></li>
                      <li><a href="template1.php?tab=leave_entitlement">Leave Entitlement</a></li>
                      <li><a href="template1.php?tab=leave_summary">Leave Summary </a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  <li><a href="./"  class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">PIM</a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
                     <?php if($_SESSION['ut'] != "Employee"){?>
                      <li><a href="template1.php?tab=employee_list">Employee List</a></li>
                      <?php } ?>
                      <li><a href="template1.php?tab=add_employee">Add Employee</a></li>
                      <li><a href="template1.php?tab=reports">Reports</a></li>

                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  <li><a href="./" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Admin</a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
                      <li><a href="template1.php?tab=termionation_reason">Termination Reason</a></li>
                      <li><a href="template1.php?tab=job_titles">Job Titles</a></li>
                      <li><a href="template1.php?tab=user_create">Add Users</a></li>
                      <li><a href="template1.php?tab=user_list">User List</a></li>
                     </ul>
                        </li>
                      <li><a href="./">Help</a></li>
                      </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</header>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

**Content.php**

```
<!-- delete ajax function begin  -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser(p)
{
   //alert (p);

//if (str=="")
//{
// document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
// return;
// }
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }

 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {

 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
     //delete table row
  var tr  = document.getElementById(p).parentNode.parentNode;
 tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
location.reload();
 }
}

var full = "?s="+p;
xmlhttp.open("GET","menu/KPI list/kpi_delete.php"+full,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}
</script>

<!-- delete ajax function end -->

<div class="body-div container padded-bottom">
 <?php

$database->getConnection();

/*
    Place code to connect to your DB here.
*/
//include('config.php');    // include your code to connect to DB.

$tbl_name="kpi";        //your table name
// How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?
$adjacents = 1;

/*
   First get total number of rows in data table.
   If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.
*/

$emp_id=$_SESSION['emp_id'];
if($_SESSION['ut'] == "Employee")
{
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name WHERE emp_id = $emp_id ";

}
else{
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name";

}

$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
$total_pages = $total_pages['num'];

/* Setup vars for query. */
$targetpage = "template1.php?tab=kpi_list";     //your file name  (the name of this file)
$limit = 1;
                                 //how many items to show per page

if(isset($_GET['page'])){
$page = $_GET['page'];
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;             //first item to display on this page
}else{
    $start = 0;
    $page=0;                            //if no page var is given, set start to 0
}
/* Get data. */
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name order by kpi_no desc LIMIT $start, $limit ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

/* Setup page vars for display. */
if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                    //if no page var is given, default to 1.
$prev = $page - 1;                            //previous page is page - 1
$next = $page + 1;                            //next page is page + 1
$lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);        //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
$lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                        //last page minus 1

/*
    Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object.
    We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
*/
$pagination = "";
if($lastpage > 1)
{
    $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination-new\">";
    //previous button
    if ($page > 1)
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage&page=$prev\">Â« previous</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">Â« previous</span>";

    //pages
    if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))    //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
    {
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
        {
            if ($counter == $page)
                $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
            else
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage&page=$counter\">$counter</a>";
        }
    }
    elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
    {
        //close to beginning; only hide later pages
        if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))
        {
            for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage&page=$counter\">$counter</a>";
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";
        }
        //in middle; hide some front and some back
        elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage&page=1\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage&page=2\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage&page=$counter\">$counter</a>";
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage&page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage&page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";
        }
        //close to end; only hide early pages
        else
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage&page=1\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage&page=2\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage&page=$counter\">$counter</a>";
            }
        }
    }

    //next button
    if ($page < $counter - 1)
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage&page=$next\">next Â»</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next Â»</span>";
    $pagination.= "</div>\n";
  }
 ?>
<!--  end of the pagination          -->

   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-ms-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <h1>KPI List</h1>
            <form action="menu/KPI list/kpi_search.php" method="post" name="testform">
            <div class="well well-sm">
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <select name="com" class="form-control">
                        <option value="f_name">First Name</option>
                        <option value="l_name">Last Name</option>
                        <option value="date">Date</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="gap clearfix"></div>
                    <!-- <div id="testform_com_errorloc" class="alert alert-danger">Error message</div>  -->
                </div>
                 <div class="pull-left">
                    <input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" value="" class="required comment form-control" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg-required="This field is required"/>
                    <div class="gap clearfix"></div>
                   <!--  <div id="testform_firstname_errorloc" class="alert alert-danger">Error message</div>  -->
                </div>
                <div class="pull-left"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default"/></div>
              </div>

           </form>
            <div class="gap"></div>

 <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>Employee First Name</th>
                <th>Employee Last Name</th>
                <th>Job Title</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>KPI given by</th>
 <?php if($_SESSION['ut'] != "Employee"){ ?>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
                <th>Give Marks</th>
                <?php } ?>
                <th>View</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <?php

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

    {
               $p = $row["kpi_no"];
                 $value = "1";
                ?>
                <td><?php echo $row['e_f_name'];; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['e_l_name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['vac_name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['kpi_given']; ?></td>
                **<?php if($_SESSION['ut'] != "Employee"){ ?>**
                <td class="text-center">
                    <a href="menu/KPI list/kpi_edit_details.php?x=<?php echo $p; ?>&v=<?php echo $page; ?>&val=<?php echo $value; ?>">
                        <!--<img width="15" height="15" src="http://localhost/project_2012/images/edit-icon.png"/>-->
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <div id="<?php  echo $p; ?>" style="width:50px; "><a href="javascript:showUser(<?php echo $p; ?>)" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')"></div>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                     <a href="menu/KPI list/give_marks.php?x=<?php echo $p; ?>&v=<?php echo $page;?>">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-certificate"></span>
                    </a>
                </td>
                **<?php }?>**
                 <td class="text-center">
                   <a href="view_vac.php?x=<?php echo $p; ?>" target="_blank">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></span>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
             <?php    } // End of while loop
    ?>
        </table>
        <!--end of table -->
         <br/><br/>
        <?php  echo $pagination; ?>

   </div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Footer.php**

```
<footer>
   <center>
    Rising Logistics<br/>
    &copy; <?php date("Y") ?> Rising Logistics, Inc. All rights reserved.
    </center>
</footer>
<!-- <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.2.8/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/common.js"></script>
```

**Logout.php:**

```
 <?php
       session_start();
        session_destroy();
        header("Location:../index.php");
 ?>
```

**Login_validaton.php**

```
        <?php
include('database.php');
include('loghis.php');
$con = $database->getConnection();

$time =   mktime(date('H')+5,date('i')+30,date('s'),date('m'),date('d'),date('Y'));

$hourr = date('H',$time);//current time hour
$minn =date('i',$time);//current time min
$secc = date('s',$time);//current time seconds
$year = date('Y',$time);//current year
$month = date('m',$time);//current month
$date = date('d',$time);//current day
$b=$year."-".$month."-".$date;
$intime = $hourr.":".$minn.":".$secc;
$username = addslashes($_POST['username']);
$password = md5(addslashes($_POST['password']));
$msg = "username or password incorrect";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='$username' and password ='$password'");

//echo $username;
 $row=mysql_num_rows($result);
//echo "1";
 if($row==1){//begin of $row count

 session_start();

 $_SESSION['uname']=$username;
 $res = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 $_SESSION['ut']=$res['emp_division'];
 $use = $res['user_name'];
 $pass = $res['password'];
 $_SESSION['emp_id'] = $res['emp_id'];
 $_SESSION['emp_division'] = $res['emp_division'];
  $logh = new loginHis;
 $logh->his($username,$b,$intime);

 header("Location:../../trunk/template1.php");

 }//end of $row count
 else {
header("Location:../../trunk/index.php?err=$msg");
}

?>
```

I have bold the PHP line in content.php file. Hope this is clear and help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Sidenote: Next time, when posting, don't use `================`, just make filenames bold. Those characters have special meaning.

Comment: Can you explain your problem clearly

Comment: technically this isn't a PHP problem. your browser is caching pages. if you want to "protect" admin pages so a back button doesn't show them anymore after logout, you'll have to make those protected pages non-cacheable.

Comment: What's in `loghis.php`?

Comment: For one thing, you'll be outputting before header with your present placement of `session_start();` should your query fail. It's best to always place it as your first line under your opening PHP tag, which in turn make your code fail. You alslo should add `exit;` after each header.

Comment: Then your `Content.php` file contains pure JS;...... *errrrrr, why??* and using MD5, that isn't a live site or intended to go live I hope. Not to mention an SQL injection. *This code will bite you back something wicked*.

Comment: Are you certain `$_SESSION['ut']=$res['emp_division'];` is being set? That appears to be the variable checked against for employees.

Comment: this could be caused by a cache somewhere. Did you try Ctrl-F5. Did you try browsing anonymously?

Comment: If he has a session access level check this cannot be a cache issue.

Comment: @Fred-ii- : there is no php error.i did a print_r in home page and session is set to 'employee' but not that specific page.so i'm clueless.Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Scott it is just a php script which records the login history details

Comment: @PaulH it works after i manally i mean after pressing F5 or the refresh button in the browser

Comment: Oh,.. so to clarify.. the page never refreshes after you login/out as an employee? You have to manually refresh the page to get the new status to take effect? And *that* is the issue?

Comment: @Scott strange thing is this has effect for this specific page only.here is the scenario : 1. I log as a admin 2. Then go the this page 3.Session set as admin 4. Login as employee 5. But in home page still the session set as admin 6. I go to another page not this page 7. Session set as employee 8. Go to this specific page again 9. Still the session set as admin 10. Manually refresh the page 11. Then it set to employee

Answer (score 2):

You could try to change the header statement in ˋLogout.phpˋ

```
header("Location:../index.php?logedout");
```

to avoid the cached page

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for this case is to define "user_type" column in you dataBase, and by the user type return the value to your session object, by that you can seperate admin users and regular users from different content.

Now you have no seperation and that's why regular users can see admin's content.

Comment: can you please explain a bit more

Comment: Yes, let's say you have 2 users: one is an admin and one is regular user.
So in your DB you will have these colums for example:
UserName, Password, Email, PhoneNumber.

When a user is trying to login, you compare the login details to the data you have in your DB, the problem is you don't know what kind of user is trying to login because you don't have that information in your database.
The solution is to add "UserType" column that defines if a user is an admin or regular user, and when a user is an admin set your session value to "admin" and by that you can choose when to display content.

Comment: I hvae a table in my db and following are the columns 1. user_name 2. password 3. emp_division 4. emp_id

Comment: Ok, so now when you check if a user exists check also it's division and by division give the right access level.

Comment: That is the case.user access level not change because Session ($_SESSION['ut'] and other session variables) not change according to the log in user.it stay as admin even though i logged as employee.but not for all the pages for some pages only